# File not Found Exception: data/data/com.dropbox.android permission denied?

Tags: android, dropbox

I developed android project, in my case i need to open a pdf file from dropbox viewer app, using this app i want to open a file in to my android app.

1. I was open pdf file in dropbox viewer app, then select “Share to” option, number of apps is listed and then i select my app.
2. I receive a file path like `“data/data/com.dropbox.android/global/preview/test.pdf”`. So i cannot able to read or write or open a pdf in to my app.

I google it, without rooting a device cannot able to read or write.
Having any other possibilities to do,

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. Most likely, you are receiving a `Uri`, not a "file path".

Comment: Yes, am getting Uri,   'uri = (Uri) extras.getParcelable(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM);
    filePath = uri.getPath();'

Answer (score 1):

```
    filePath = uri.getPath();
```

That is useless. A `Uri` is not a file. [Use a `ContentResolver` and methods like `openInputStream()`](https://commonsware.com/blog/2016/03/15/how-consume-content-uri.html) to work with the `Uri`.

Comment: Same thing i used but its cannot work , "InputStream attachment = context.getContentResolver().openInputStream(contentURI);" . Issue throws in that line only.

Comment: @user6261979: "Issue throws in that line only" -- I have no idea what this means.

Comment: when execute above line , I have an exception "File not found: permission denied",

Comment: @user6261979: I do not know what `contentURI` is; your earlier comment showed your `EXTRA_STREAM` being put in `uri`. If you are faithfully passing the `Uri` from `EXTRA_STREAM` into `openInputStream()`, and you cannot read the stream, you will have to take that up with Dropbox.

Comment: "contentURI = file:///data/data/com.dropbox.android/global/external/docpreviews/2091.pdf" this URI i get it from dropbox viewer app

Comment: @user6261979: Then that's a bug in the Dropbox app, as you cannot access that.